# SQL SELECT statement to check for duplicate email not working with PHP variable

Tags: php, sql, variables

I have a subscribe component which is a simple form which looks like this:

```
<form id="newsletter_subscribe">        

    <label class="label-margin">Email<span class="required-field">*</label>
    <input type="email" name="mailinglistEmail">

    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="subscribe-button float-r"> 
    <div class="clear_float"></div>

 </form>
```

using a combination of jquery and ajax I serialize the data and send it through to the process file like this  (my apologies if I'm pasting too much code, but I'd rather paste everything than too little):

```
$(function() {

$("#newsletter_subscribe").submit(function(event) {

    //SUPPRESS SUBMIT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR
    event.preventDefault();

    //STRINGIFY THE SERIALIZED OBJECT OF THE FORM AND PACK INTO VARIABLE JSONstring
    var JSONstring = JSON.stringify($("#newsletter_subscribe").serializeObject());

    //AJAX REQUEST TO THE SERVER
    var subscribeRequest = $.ajax({
       url: "mailinglist-process-test.php", //URL PARAMETER CONTAINS A STRING OF THE URL SENDING THE REQUEST TO
       type: "POST",        //THE TYPE OF REQUEST BEING SENT, IE GET, POST ETC       
       data: JSONstring,    //THE ACTUAL DATA SENT TO THE SERVER WITH THE AJAX REQUEST  
       dataType: "json",    //THE TYPE OF DATA EXPECTED BACK FROM THE SERVER     
       cache: false,        //SET THIS TO FALSE TO FORCE REQUESTED PAGES TO NOT BE CACHED IN THE BROWSER         
    });
    console.log(subscribeRequest);
    //THINGS TO HAPPEN AFTER SUCCESSFUL REQUEST 
    subscribeRequest.then(function(result){
        $("#newsletter_subscribe").hide();
        queryResult = result;
        return success(queryResult);

        }).then(function(message){
                $("#subscribe_success").html(message);
            }); 

    // ########### SUCCESS FUNCTION START        
    function success(queryResult) {
        subscribed = queryResult.userSubscribe;
        if (subscribed == 'yes'){
            message = "You have successfully signed up for our newsletter.";
        }

        if (subscribed == 'duplicate'){
            message = "This email address is already subscribed.";
        } 
        return message;
    }   
    // ########### SUCCESS FUNCTION END                         
});
```

});

Now in the process file, before I insert into the db I want to check if the email is already in the db! I'm trying to do this like so:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$vMailinglistDate = date('Y-m-d');

$vMailinglistEmail = strtolower(trim($data['mailinglistEmail']));   

$sql_mailinglist = "SELECT * FROM tblmailinglist WHERE MailinglistEmail = $vMailinglistEmail " ;

require('cms/inc-conn-tekiah.php');

$rs_mailinglist = mysqli_query($vConnTekiah, $sql_mailinglist);

$rs_mailinglistRows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_mailinglist);

if ($rs_mailinglistRows === 0) {            

    require('inc-conn-tekiah.php');
    require('inc-function-escapestring.php'); 

    //FORMULATE THE INSERT STATEMENT    
    $sql_subscribe = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblmailinglist (MailinglistDate, MailinglistEmail) VALUES (%s, %s)",
    escapestring($vConnTekiah, $vMailinglistDate, 'text'),
    escapestring($vConnTekiah, $vMailinglistEmail, 'text')
    );

    $sql_subscribeResult = mysqli_query($vConnTekiah, $sql_subscribe);
```

... etc. insert process continues.

After testing and trying to figure out why this wasn't producing the result I wanted I figured out it was because the mysqli_result from the query was null! Even though the email I tested with was definitely already in the db.

More testing revealed that if I used this select statement and typed the email I was testing as a string in single quotes, it worked fine:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblmailinglist WHERE MailinglistEmail = 'test@gmail.com' ";
```

But using the variable, the SELECT statement outputs a string that looks like this which clearly isn't working:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblmailinglist WHERE MailinglistEmail = test@gmail.com ";
```

The only difference I can see is the single quotes in the first version that seem to make it work. What is really confusing though, is that I've been using variables in previous SELECT statements with no issue at all.

So my question is, what approach should I take to construct a SELECT statement to test for a duplicate email using what information I have (the email sent in the form to test if it's already in the DB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First method. That is the syntax in `mysql`. So add single quotes by yourself

```
$sql_mailinglist = "SELECT * FROM tblmailinglist WHERE MailinglistEmail = '$vMailinglistEmail' " ;
                                                                          ^                  ^
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried concatenating the single quotes in but that was a mess. Don't know why I didn't think of just adding them in like that! Thank you very much.